# Who are these Game of Thrones "Summer is here" characters?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, character-identification

I recently saw this awesome image by artist Tim Hamilton ([@T1mco](https://twitter.com/T1mco))

[image: Game of Thrones - "Summer is here" artwork]

<sub>[src: http://t1mco.tumblr.com/post/90437781995]</sub>

I'm interested to know if anyone can help me figure out who is in the photo?
There are some who are clearly obvious, but some which are not.

**Who are these Game of Thrones (ASOIAF) characters?**

Comment: You rep farmer!

Comment: In the foreground: **Ned** and **Catelyn**; **Cersei** and **Jaime**. At the very back: **Oberyn** and **Ellaria**; **Varys** and ???; **Daenerys**, **Jorah**, and I guess two of Irri, Jhiqui, and Missandei. In the pool: **Bran** on **Hodor**, **Ygritte** on **Jon**, probably **Arya**, and some others I'm not sure of (maybe Night Watch people?) On the concrete behind the pool: **Rickon**, **Gregor** (?). That's about as far as I can get.

Comment: **Samwell** and **Gilly** next to **Ghost** on the right of the pool. **Tyrion** at the BBQ is obvious, probably with **Shae**. The huffy blond kid with the red pants in the background is likely to be **Joffrey** and since a dog is with them, one of the girls should be **Sansa**, the blond guy lying around could be **Loras** (which could make the other girl **Margery**?).

Comment: @Axelrod I prefer rep-whore thank you very much!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From foreground to background, then left to right:

### This side of the pool

- **Ned** and **Cat** taking some rest. Ned appears to be drinking [Red Stripe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Stripe); presumably [Newky Brown Ale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcastle_Brown_Ale) wasn't an option
- **Cersei** and **Jaime** on a date. Cersei's glammed up in a red dress and looks to be on her second bottle of wine already, Jaime's posing in a designer polo shirt.

### In the pool

- **Robb** and [**Talisa/Jeyne** Westerling] play with **Grey Wind**, with two unidentifiable characters. Based on how other characters cluster and interact in this image, I'd guess it's **Theon** awkwardly being the couple's third wheel and [**Asha/Yara**] swimming over to stop him making a nuisance of himself.
- **Bran** riding **Hodor** plays with **Rickon** and **Shaggydog**, while **Summer**, **Jojen** and **Meera** watch
- **Jon**, **Ygritte**, **Gendry** and **Hot Pie** try to dodge **Arya** cannonballing into the pool
- **Gilly**, holding what is presumably her baby, chats to a blushing **Sam**, while **Nymeria** and **Ghost** sit by the side of the pool watching their humans foolishly playing, wearing what look like expressions of wolfish disdain

### On the path around the pool

- **Gregor** sits and eats, not caring that he's in the way of anyone trying to walk past

### Behind that path

- **Loras** chats to a blushing **Sansa** while **Margaery** does her hair and half-listens to a scowling **Joffrey**. **Lady** takes a nap
- **Olena** and **Twyin** relax and watch the silly oafs at play while smirking from some shade, presumably giving some shade of their own
- **Sandor** lies back and relaxes, while keeping an eye on Gregor. I think it's Sandor since there seems to be the burnt gap in his hair, but he looks a bit skinny for Sandor. It could also be Bronn with a side parting, sitting near Tyrion but not getting involved in Tyrion's family stuff
- **Tyrion** makes a big show of giving food to **Tommen** and **Myrcella**, while **Shae** does all the hard work. [credit to SystemDown] Tommen's cats, **Ser Pounce** and **Balerion**, are skulking by Tommen's feet, clearly aware it's meal time.

### Beyond the Wall

- **Oberyn** and **Ellaria** take a romantic stroll
- **Varys**, holding what looks like a little bird, and presumably **Littlefinger** take a stroll, though the likeness isn't clear this far out. It's possibly a better likeness for **Illyrio Mopatis** with Varys, which would make sense, but would leave us with the (always worrying) question, where is Littlefinger and what is he up to? The guy on the sunlounger near Tywin could be Littlefinger from his build and face, and it'd make sense for him to be near but not with the other arch-schemers, but the hair's not right.
- **Jorah** (presumably, though the likeness isn't clear this far out) follows behind Dany, loyally carrying all her stuff while she ignores him and chats to other people
- **Dany** strolls and chats with **Jhiqui** (darker) and **Irri** (lighter). I'm assuming it's them, because no other pair of Dany's female companions are close enough that you'd expect them to walk arm in arm like this. It is known.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's Sandor, not Bronn.

Comment: Looking again, I think you're right

Comment: Love the running commentary! I think that's grilled octopus on a stick in Varys' hand.

Comment: @SystemDown making me hungry. Actually, looking closer, I think it's a little bird... two raised wings and a beak pointed towards Varys like it's just landing on his hand and is telling him something. Probably also tastes good grilled.

Comment: I think you're right. Also, I think that's Balerion and Ser Pounce lounging around Tommen's feet, hoping for a treat.

Comment: Nice, well spotted! Bet there's more little details like that, can't see any though

Comment: everyone! Looks like you've got everyone spot-on :) Thank you for sharing and discussing this pic, and I hope you all had fun trying to identify everyone!

Comment: @T1mco Thanks for posting and confirming that these are correct!

Comment: For those wondering, [I've confirmed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lYKqk.jpg) that this is the original artist of the image.

Comment: Also, that's 100% Littlefinger with Varys since he's got greying hair on the sides.

Comment: Hi @T1mco thanks for the reply and thanks or making the image, it's great! Just wanting to confirm some of the ones I was less sure about: can you confirm who is on the sunlounger between Tywin and Tyrion, and who the guy with Varys is? Also who the pair in the water by Robb and co are? Thanks!